# Creating files in succession

Tags: bash, shell

How would one go about creating a script for creating 25 empty files in succession? (I.e 1-25, 26-51, 52-77)

I can create files 1-25 but I’m having trouble figuring out how to create a script that continues that process from where it left off, every time I run the script.

Comment: How are you creating the initial 25?

Comment: For i in {1..25}

Do touch <filename> $i

Comment: Read the name of the higher existing file and do your `for` on that up to that + 25

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @Nic3500 can you please show me an example? I’m a little slow lol

Comment: I’m still having trouble understanding this script lol

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

higher=$( find files -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort -n | tail -1 )

if [[ "$higher" == "" ]]
then
    start=1
    end=25
else
    (( start = higher + 1 ))
    (( end = start + 25 ))
fi

echo "$start --> $end"

for i in $(seq $start 1 $end)
do
    touch files/"$i"
done
```

- I put my files in a directory called "files".
- hence the `find` on directory "files".
- for each file found, I run a basename on it.  That will return only integer values, since the files all have a number filename.
- `sort -n` puts them in order.
- `tail -1` extracts the highest number.
- if there are no files, higher will be empty, so the indexes will be 1 and 25.
- otherwise, they will be higher + 1, and higher + 26.
- I used `seq` for the `for` loop to avoid problems with variables inside a range definition (you did {1..25})

Answer (score 0):

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

declare -r base="${1:-base-%d.txt}"
declare -r lot="${2:-25}"
declare -i idx=1
declare -i n=0

printf -v filename "${base}" ${idx}
while [[ -e "${filename}" ]]; do
    idx+=1
    printf -v filename "${base}" "${idx}"
done
while [[ $n -lt $lot ]]; do
    printf -v filename "${base}" ${idx}
    if [[ ! -e "${filename}" ]]; then
        > "$filename"
        n+=1
    fi
    idx+=1
done
```

This script accepts two optional parameters.

1. The first is the basename of your future files with a `%d` token automatically replaced by the file number. Default value is `base-%d.txt`;
2. The number of file to create. Default value is `25`.

How script works:

1. Variable declarations

   - `base`: file basename (constant)
   - `lot`: number of file to create (constant)
   - `idx`: search index
   - `n`: counter for new files
2. Search files already created from 1

   - The loop stop at first hole in the numbering
3. Loop to create empty files

   - The condition in the loop allows to fill in the numbering holes
   - `> filename` create an empty file